# Deadlock necessary conditions

Tags: operating-systems, deadlocks

I read that the 4 conditions for deadlock prevention are necessary conditions and **not sufficient**.

The four necessary conditions are :-

1. Mutual exclusion.
2. Hold and wait.
3. No preemption.
4. Circular wait.

Here it is clearly mentioned that these conditions are only necessary but not sufficient. 
https://cs.nyu.edu/courses/spring03/V22.0202-002/lecture-06.html

Can someone please tell me why are they not sufficient? I am not able to come up with an example where all the conditions satisfy but deadlock doesn't occur.

Comment: Which 4 conditions are you talking about?

Comment: The answer says that **there is no situation where the four conditions are satisfied and there is no deadlock**. Then why are the conditions not sufficient ?

Comment: That duplicate doesn't answer my question.